# Warning message from databases in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I received the following message from Firebase. What am I supposed to do?

> You chose to start developing in Test Mode, which leaves your Realtime
> Database instance completely open to the Internet. Because this choice
> makes your app vulnerable to attackers, your database security rules
> were configured to stop allowing requests after the first 30 days. In
> 5 day(s), all client requests to your Realtime Database instance will
> be denied. Before that time, please update your security rules to
> allow your app to function while appropriately protecting your data.
> Analysis is run daily; if you've modified your rules in the last 24
> hours those changes may not be accounted for.

And this is what I found in databases in Firebase

```
{
  "rules": {

    ".read": "now < 1602709200000",  // 2020-10-15

    ".write": "now < 1602709200000",  // 2020-10-15
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set this conditions in Realtime Database Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some security rules for your database other than the current ones. [You should read about how to define them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

Your current rules mean that everyone can read and write to your database if their requests are sent before 15th October 2020. So unless you set them in the next 5 days, your service will be unavailable after that.

Comment: I'd also recommend reading this part of the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules